# WKWebView view not resizable

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard

I'm creating a macOS Swift app, I'm new to Swift. I'm trying to make the view resizable like web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), however my code doesn't seem to work, and I didn't find anything useful about WKWebView resizing.

Here's my code for the ViewController:

```swift
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKUIDelegate
    {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView()
    {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration ();
        webConfiguration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs");
        webView = WKWebView (frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:1920, height:1080), configuration:webConfiguration);
        webView.uiDelegate = self;
            self.view = webView;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.webView.frame.size.height))
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }  
}
```

Results:
[image: Does not resize webview when window is resized]

Comment: Are you aware that you're adding a second webview?

Comment: I didn't know about it, I only need one webview.

Comment: You might want to search for "autolayout" and "constraints"

Comment: How is the view not resizable? What happens when you do what and what should happen?

Comment: The webview should resize with the window, but check out the image I just edited the question, content shouldn't stay straight like that and should resize.

Comment: Did you remove the second webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to fix the issue with Willeke's recommendation:

Replace this:

```swift
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.webView.frame.size.height))
self.view.addSubview(webView)
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

With this:

```swift
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.roblox.com/") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```